# Show / Hide Select Field on Checkbox within Appended-Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

My problem is as followed: I've got dynamic div-boxes in which I append some input fields including a styled checkbox and a hidden select field. The select field should only appear, when the user checks the box beside. So you click on "[+]" when you need more than one div-box (in which the checkbox and hidden select field are) and make your input. I already tried some possible solutions, but none of them seemed to work. The current status is that I can add these divs which contain the input fields, but only the "static" one works with the function show / hide the select field onclick checkbox. The appended ones always show the select field. Here's the code:

```
// JAVASCRIPT
$(document).ready(function() {
    // DYNAMIC RD ADD
    // ROUNDS
    // MAXIMUM DIV BOXES ALLOWED
    var rd_max_fields      = 15;
    // FIELDS WRAPPER
    var rd_wrapper         = $(".rd_input_fields_wrap");
    // ADD DIV BUTTON ID
    var rd_add_button      = $(".rd_add_field_button");

    // INITIAL DIV BOX COUNT               
    var rd_x = 1; //initlal text box count
    // ADD DIV CONTAINER
    $(rd_add_button).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // MAX DIV ALLOWED
        if(rd_x < rd_max_fields){
            // DIV BOX INCREMENT
            rd_x++;
            // ADD INPUT TEXT
            $(rd_wrapper).append('<div><table id="addrd" width="385px" "cellspacing="5px" style="border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF; border-top: 0; border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF; border-bottom: 0;"><tr><th colspan="2">&nbsp;</th></tr><tr><th colspan="2"><hr class="white-hr" /></th></tr><tr><th colspan="2">&nbsp;</th></tr></table><a href="#" class="rd_remove_field"><table id="addrd" width="385px" "cellspacing="5px" style="border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF; border-top: 0; border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF; border-bottom: 0;"><tr><th align="left">Prüfung entfernen</th><th align="right"><font color="#FFD700">[&ndash;]</font></th></tr></table></a><tr><th colspan="2"><hr /></th></tr></table><table width="385px" "cellspacing="5px" style="border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF; border-top: 0; border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF; border-bottom: 0;"><tr><td align="left">Prüfungsnummer<font color="#8E6516">*</font></td><td align="right"><input name="rd_id[]" type="text" style="background: transparent; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #8E6516; width: 135px;" placeholder="' + rd_x + '" required="required" /></td></tr><tr><td align="left">Sollzeit<font color="#8E6516">*</font></td><td align="right"><input name="rd_id[]" type="text" style="background: transparent; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #8E6516; width: 135px;" placeholder="Bsp. ' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 7) + 1) + ':' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 49) + 10) + '" required="required" /></td></tr><tr><td align="left">Zwischenzeit?</td><td align="right"><table width="135px" cellspacing="0" style="border: 0;"><tr><td align="left"><div class="checkboxOne"><input type="checkbox" value="yes" id="checkboxOneInput_' + rd_x + '" name="rd_id[]"/><label for="checkboxOneInput_' + rd_x + '"></label></div></td><td align="right"><select name="rd_id[]" id="rd_id_zz" class="zz" placeholder="Anzahl" style="background: transparent; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #8E6516; width: 75px;" ><option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Zeiten</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option></select></td></tr></table></td></tr></tr></table></div>');
        }
    });
    // USER CLICK TO REMOVE DIV
    $(rd_wrapper).on("click",".rd_remove_field", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); 
    rd_x--;
    });

    // STATIC CHECKBOX
    $("#rd_id_zz").hide();
    $("#checkboxOneInput").click(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("#rd_id_zz").prop('disabled', false);
            $("#rd_id_zz").show(500, 'easeInSine');
        } else {
            $("#rd_id_zz").hide(500, 'easeOutSine');
        }
    });
});

// HTML
<div class="rd_input_fields_wrap" id="rd_input_fields_wrap">
    <table width="385px" cellspacing="5px" style="border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF; border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF; border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF; border-bottom: 0;">
        <tr>
            <th align="left">Prüfung(en) hinzufügen</th>
            <th align="right"><a href="#" class="rd_add_field_button" id="add_field"><font color="#FFD700">[+]</font></a></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2"><hr /></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
<div>
<table id="addrd" width="385px" cellspacing="5px" style="border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF; border-top: 0; border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF; border-bottom: 0;">
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Bezeichnung<font color="#8E6516">*</font></td>
        <td align="right">
            <select name="rd_type" id="rd_type" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Bitte auswählen" style="background: transparent; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #8E6516; width: 135px;" required="required" onclick="disable();" >
                <option selected='selected' disabled='disabled'>Bitte auswählen</option>";
                <option value='GP'>GP</option>
                <option value='WP'>WP</option>
                <option value='SP'>SP</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Prüfungsnummer<font color="#8E6516">*</font></td>
        <td align="right"><input id="rd_id_pn" name="rd_id[]" type="text" style="background: transparent; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #8E6516; width: 135px;" placeholder="Bsp. 1" required="required" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Sollzeit<font color="#8E6516">*</font></td>
        <td align="right"><input id="rd_id_sz" name="rd_id[]" type="text" style="background: transparent; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #8E6516; width: 135px;" placeholder="Bsp. 2:30" required="required" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Zwischenzeit?</td>
        <td align="right">
            <table width="135px" cellspacing="0" style="border: 0;">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                        <div class="checkboxOne">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="yes" id="checkboxOneInput" name="rd_id[]"/>
                            <label for="checkboxOneInput"></label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td align="right">
                        <select name="rd_id[]" id="rd_id_zz" class="zz" placeholder="Anzahl" style="background: transparent; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #8E6516; width: 75px;" >
                            <option selected='selected' disabled='disabled'>Zeiten</option>
                            <option value='1'>1</option>
                            <option value='2'>2</option>
                            <option value='3'>3</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And here's the fiddle* to it:

[Show / Hide Select Field on Checkbox within Appended-Content](https://jsfiddle.net/Labushuya/9a63omoh/4/)

**note:** 
*the select field does'nt seem to .hide() on click there; on my page it works fine with .show() and .hide()*

**EDIT**
Question: How can I combine the dynamic adding of another set of input fields with the show / hide onclick checkbox (checkswitch)? At the moment only the "static" one works (you click on the checkswitch and the select field appears (and should disappear again when you click)).

Comment: "but only the "static" one works with the function show / hide the select field onclick checkbox. The appended ones always show the select field" 
can you explain more detail?

Comment: I only want the appended ones (over [+]) work like the div, which is already there.

Comment: Oh you only want to duplicate it?

Comment: Exactly! If you add another set, exactly the same "procedure" should appear: You make your input and if you want "zwischenzeit", you check the box and make your selection. That's all

Comment: Try my new build ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood this build will help you

https://jsfiddle.net/devsullo/9a63omoh/8/

Advice: do not use static `id`-s in generated html code

EDIT: try this https://jsfiddle.net/devsullo/9a63omoh/11/

Comment: Kinda. The part with toggling was only a side-problem. The problem is, that if I add another set of this input fields, the select option still needs to be hidden until you click on the checkbutton (checkswitch). But I implemented you toggle function :)

Comment: It's exactly what I want, but the checkbox has to be checked first and then the select field appears. And the other way around: You uncheck and the select field disappears

Comment: its unchecked already, add css and thats all .zz{ display:none; }

Comment: Wohoo! Many thanks my friend! It works exactly as I expected!

Comment: Regards from Georgia )))